# AWS Distributed Load Testing requests and responses logging

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, load-testing

Is it possible to view result of each request in AWS Distributed Load Testing like it is in result tree in JMeter application? If yes, where I can see it?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Container image customization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/container-image.html) page AWS Distributed Load Testing uses [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) under the hood.

Therefore you can customize the image and configure [JMeter Test Log](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Test-Log) to store full request and response data and not only the errors.

If you need to learn more about Taurus check out [The Complete Taurus Course](https://www.blazemeter.com/university/complete-taurus-course) from the Taurus tool vendor.